# How to use one type of quotation mark in a multilingual document?

Tags: babel, languages, csquotes

I want to create a personal template for theses etc. in which I would like to use Guillemets. Since I do not want them to be in the way of >>lorem<<, but << lorem>>, I decided to use the `swiss` option.
Now I included several languages with my babel package, but as soon as I want to set `swiss`for all lnguages, Latex tells me `Quote style not defined`. 
My code looks like this and maybe one of you could help me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english,french,bulgarian,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=swiss,english=swiss,french=swiss,bulgarian=swiss,russian=swiss]{csquotes}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of csquotes, there is no quote style predefined for Russian, and Bulgarian isn't even mentioned among the supported languages there (see table 2). 
The documentation is not very clear about it: "Quote Styles and Style Variants Defined by Default" could mean that these are just the default values which one is free to change. However, it seems that certain quote styles are not allowed for certain languages (so, for English you can only choose between "american" and "british", but not "swiss").

As you want to use one style for all languages, you don't need to set the style for each language separately. Just set it globally!

```
\usepackage[babel,style=swiss]{csquotes}
```

That should be enough to put Swiss-style quotation marks around all your quotes, no matter what language you are using.